# Не возвращает фото профиля

Tags: telegram, бот, telebot, python-3.8

```
print(update.message.bot.get_user_profile_photos(update.effective_user.id, 0))
```

Когда открыта переписка с ботом - возвращает фото профиля, иначе возвращает `{'total_count': 0, 'photos': []}`.
Возможно сделать так, чтобы всегда возвращались фото профиля?

Comment: Я точно не знаю, но как на счет настроек приватности телеграм? Если пользователь запретил брать его фотографию, то каким образом это сделает бот?

Answer (score 0):

Это может быть из-за настроек приватности или из-за того что у пользователя нет фото. Кстати сами фото хранятся в массиве photos.